# Android custom dialog wrong dimensions

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to make a custom dialog in Android. Everything works perfectly except that the height of the dialog is too big and it looks bad. I attached an image to see how it looks: http://i42.tinypic.com/14t1lp4.jpg

I only need the button part to show. Also, it would be nice if the white contour would dissapear as well.
This is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" android:drawingCacheQuality="high" android:textSize="18dip"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButton"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Button" android:background="@drawable/buttond" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code in your Custom Dialog Box's constructor or wherever you call `setContentView()`-

```
try {
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will save lot of space from your dialog.

**NOTE** : Put the above code BEFORE `setContentView()`